# Rust import trait for unqualified usage

Tags: rust, traits

I've been learning Rust recently and I prefer the syntax of calling functions rather than methods. I just discovered the Universal function call syntax, and it offers what I was looking for.

I can turn this chain:

```
a.into_iter().zip(b.into_iter()).fold(0.0, |sum, (x, y)| sum + x * y)
```

Into:

```
Iterator::fold(
    Iterator::zip(IntoIterator::into_iter(a), IntoIterator::into_iter(b)), 
    0.0, |sum, (x, y)| sum + x * y)
```

However I would really like to get rid of the verbosity of this statement, what I want to write is:

```
fold(zip(into_iter(a), into_iter(b)), 0.0, |sum, (x, y)| sum + x * y)
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this, in C++ I would have `using namespace ...` to get rid of these qualified calls, but I can't find a rust equivalent (if there is one).

*Minimal Example*

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
    let b = vec![4.0, 5.0, 6.0];

    // I want to change this line
    let result = a.into_iter().zip(b).fold(0, |sum, (x, y)| sum + x * y);

    println!("{}", result);
 }
```

Comment: The closest language to C++ is C++ itself. If you want to keep all your idioms, just keep using C++.

Comment: Not related, but I'd prefer that style that better expresses the intent: `a.into_iter().zip(b).map(|p| p.0 * p.1).sum()`

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I wouldn't call it much of an idiom... and certainly not a C++ specific one. Infact I find it highly abnormal to use something like `number.log()` instead of `log(number)`. Thank you for your snippet, that does look better to me, I have largely based my code on what I find in the book.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Was superfluous info, I removed it.

Comment: Also your example would look much nicer to me as: `sum(map(zip(into_iter(a), into_iter(b)), |(x, y)| x * y))`. I find it much easier to read this, hence my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get closer to what you want with [use declarations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/use-declarations.html)

```
use std::iter::IntoIterator as ito;
use std::iter::Iterator as it;

fn main() {
    let a = vec![2.3, 4.0];
    let b = vec![5.6, 7.0];
    //let result = a
    //    .into_iter()
    //    .zip(b.into_iter())
    //    .fold(0.0, |sum, (x, y)| sum + x * y);
    let result = it::fold(
        it::zip(ito::into_iter(a), ito::into_iter(b)),
        0.0,
        |sum, (x, y)| sum + x * y,
    );
    println!("result {}", result);!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did play with this and it does seem like my best option right now. I would still prefer to omit the qualifier entirely if possible though.

Comment: You are right. I agree that it still looks clunky in this style with the qualifiers.  
Maybe have a second look at the method chaining syntax and let `rustfmt` format it for you. It usually produces nicely readable code.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

As the compiler very explicitly tells you, methods cannot be imported directly:

```
error[E0253]: `fold` is not directly importable
 --> src/lib.rs:1:5
1 | use std::iter::Iterator::fold;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot be imported directly
```

or

```
error: items in traits are not importable.
 --> src/lib.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use std::iter::Iterator::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[(Permalink to the playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bcf5cbe068afb3b0473408f5529591a9)

Note that your comparison with `using namespace` is not correct. `Iterator` is a trait, not a module (Rust's equivalent of namespaces). In C++, you wouldn't try to import `std::string::size` and then use `size(my_string)`.

---

As for why you can't:

Your way requires a lot of nesting (which most will argue *reduces* readability), prevents autocompletion and is not idiomatic in Rust. Method syntax is *the* way to go in Rust. Do not fight idioms of one language because they are different from idioms of languages you are more familiar with.

Method syntax does have advantages.

It is true that in C++, free functions are usually preferred over methods, but this is mostly because method are necessarily tied to the implementation of a 
class. They must be declared within the class declaration, which provides tight coupling. Rust does not have this issue, as methods can belong to traits, and anyone can add methods to any type (including built-in types, which C++ cannot do at all).

Finally, note that even C++ has had proposal to have method syntax everywhere (see [N4174](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf) by Bjarne Stroustrup and [N4165](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4165.pdf) by Herb Sutter). This shows that this syntax has advantages.